# slash gets changed to backslash in the app direction

Tags: node.js, express, path

I'm using `node` and `express` in my app and `web server for chrome` to serve web pages from a local folder over the network. I wanna direct the app to a page this way:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

but it does not work and by using `console.log()`, this path is shown:

```
D:\node\project10\index.html
```

as you see slashes are changed to backslashes. also tried to solve it this way:

```
path.join(__dirname.replace(/\\/g,"/") + '/index.html'))
```

Without `path.join` the problem is solved but with having it the problem remains.

how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you console.log() the path.join() it shows the dashes in the other direction because windows is working like that. In the browser the dashes are: '/' but in the windows are opposite. So the problem is not from the dashes.

Comment: when i submit infos form a form it takes me to a page showing this message: `Unhandled request. Did you select a folder to serve?` and this one on Chrome's console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. Do you know about this??

Comment: Maybe you don't get or post the method in the server.